# France long-stay visa

Tags: visa, working-visas, france, indian-citizens, india

I submitted applications for long stay visa for myself and my wife over a month ago in India. My visa category is talent visa and my wife is going as my family. My work contract in an university as a postdoctoral fellow is for two years.

Usually, it takes 3 weeks for getting the visa approvals. But

- In general, Why does it take so much time for getting long stay visas ?

Nowadays, short stays are getting approved within 5 days! Another friend of mine who is going France for an **year** to study, also got the visa within 7 days!!

- Could there be any specific reason for delay that is particular to my case ?

Comment: The one-year study visa is also a long-stay visa, making your first question moot (although 7 days sounds really fast to be honest). Difficult to know if that means anything, I wouldn't worry just yet, a month is not terribly long. You also applied during a time when a ton of people are on holiday in France.